# Piscar um texto no Tkinter / Efeito colateral

Tags: python, tkinter

Olá, Estou iniciando meus estudos em Python, com o uso do Tkinter. Peguem leve nas respostas / criticas (rs!).
Preciso "piscar" um texto (blink), com um valor, quando este for o mais rápido (recorde da volta).
Busquei informações em vários lugares de como fazer isto de forma simples, mas só achei resultados utilizando o método ".after".
Porém, surgiu um efeito colateral, fazendo desta forma. Após algumas "piscadas", ele vai ficando mais lento.
Minhas dúvidas, são:
1) Tem algo errado do jeito que eu fiz?
2) Tem outra forma de fazer um texto piscar?

Abaixo um resumo do que eu fiz, apresentando o problema ("piscada" ficando lento).

```
from tkinter import * # Python 3
Piscando=0

class Janela_Treino:
    def __init__ (self,janela):
        janela_treino = Canvas(0, width=800, height=600, bg="black")

        def Placar():
            global Piscando
            x = 0
            while x < 4:
                if (x == 2): # Teste para piscar a posição 3
                    if Piscando == 0:
                        janela_treino.create_text(400, 75+(150*x),text="00:000", font=('Arial', 120, 'bold'), fill="black") # Esconde
                        Piscando = 1
                    else:
                        janela_treino.create_text(400, 75+(150*x),text="00:000", font=('Arial', 120, 'bold'), fill="white") # Mostra
                        Piscando = 0
                else:
                    janela_treino.create_text(400, 75+(150*x), text="00:000", font=('Arial', 120, 'bold'), fill="white") # Mostra normal
                x=x+1
            janela.after(100,Placar) # Atualiza a tela a cada 0.1 segundo                

        Placar()
        janela_treino.pack()        

root = Tk()
Janela_Treino(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

A ideia básica está correta - a forma de se manter algo animado no tkinter, mesmo texto piscando, é ter uma função ou método que é chamada por um timer como o que você faz em `janela.after`.

O problema fundamental aí é que você não levou em conta como o Canvas  do tkinter funciona: ele não simplesmente desenha o texto na tela, como pixels, e esquece desse texto. Se ele fizesse só isso, na próxima execução da sua função `Placar`, ele criaria outro texto, com outra cor, por cima, e tudo bem.

Só que quando se desenha um objeto no Canvas do Tkinter esse objeto fica "vivo": ele tem atributos e cores, e pode ser movido - o Canvas do Tkinter é um canvas "vetorial": ele redesenha todos os objetos que foram criados nele a cada vez que é atualizado.

E aí que o seu código, a cada piscada, cria um **novo** objeto de texto, e insere ele no Canvas - o que acontece é que o Canvas desenha TODOS os textos que você criou, de quando ele foi criado até o último, um por cima do outro - e só realmente atualiza o que está na tela quando acabou de desenhar em background.

Parece que fica claro por que após uns 20 ou 30 ciclos isso vai começar a ficar lento - ele tem que desenhar, um por cima do outro o texto 20 ou 30 vezes -- com mais tempo - em apenas um minuto, seriam 600 objetos de texto, não tem CPU que aguente!

Então - a correção é simples: se fosse realmente necessário criar um novo objeto de texto em cada frame, seria só uma questão de apagar o texto antigo - o método `create_text` devolve um número inteiro (que você não guarda em lugar nenhum no seu código - ele é jogado fora) - esse número é o *identificador* (handler) daquele objeto dentro do Canvas, e ele é necessário para se apagar um objeto, ou mudar um dos seus parâmetros.

Então, guardando esse número, seria uma questão de chamar o método `janela_treino.delete(...)` com ele para apagar o texto anterior, antes de criar um texto novo.

Mas - a coisa é mais simples ainda - tendo em vista que vocẽ quer manter o texto, a fonte, a posição, etc - -e quer só mudar a cor, é só reconfigurar o objeto texto com a cor desejada. O mesmo número identificador do texto é usado, mas com o método `itemconfig`. O código pode ficar assim:

```
from tkinter import * # Python 3

class Janela_Treino:
    def __init__ (self,janela):
        piscando = False
        janela_treino = Canvas(0, width=800, height=600, bg="black")
        identificador_texto = janela_treino.create_text(400, 75+(150),text="00:000", font=('Arial', 120, 'bold'), fill="black")


        def placar():
            nonlocal piscando
            if piscando:
                color = "black"
            else:
                color = "white"


            janela_treino.itemconfig(identificador_texto, fill=color)
            piscando = not piscando
            janela.after(100, placar) # Atualiza a tela a cada 0.1 segundo

        placar()
        janela_treino.pack()

root = Tk()
Janela_Treino(root)
root.mainloop()
```

(esse código apenas pisca o texto - ajuste os contadores e "if" para piscar em frames específicos - e use o método `.move` do canvas para mudar a posição do texto, como seu código original fazia, se desejar)