# Como fazer um botão piscar Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Estou tentando fazer uma tela em que os botões piscam em determinadas frequências. Não consegui encontrar nenhuma função que atendesse. Alguém pode me ajudar, por gentileza?

Segue o código que fiz por enquanto:

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()
janela.title("ICM")
janela["bg"] = "black"
janela.geometry("900x600+200+0") #LxA+Esq+Topo

lb1 = Button(janela, width = 30, height = 5, text = "CIMA", bg="red")
lb2 = Button(janela, width = 30, height = 5, text = "BAIXO", bg="red")
lb3 = Button(janela, width = 30, height = 5, text = "DIREITA", bg="red")
lb4 = Button(janela, width = 30, height = 5, text = "ESQUERDA", bg="red")
lb5 = Button(janela, width = 30, height = 5, text = "START", bg="white")
lb6 = Button(janela, width = 30, height = 5, text = "STOP", bg="white")

lb1.grid(row=0,column=3, padx= 100, pady=10) #cima
lb2.grid(row=5,column=3,padx= 100, pady=10) #baixo
lb3.grid(row=3,column=0,padx= 10, pady=100) #direita
lb4.grid(row=3,column=5,padx= 10, pady=100) #esquerda
lb5.grid(row=5,column=0,padx= 10, pady=100) #start
lb6.grid(row=5,column=5,padx= 10, pady=100) #stop

janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Essa pergunta tem uma resposta aqui - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/263557/piscar-um-texto-no-tkinter-efeito-colateral/374046   - a sua não pode ser marcada como uma duplicata, por que o autor da outra pergunta não se deu ao trabalho de verificar a resposta dada. Mas resuidamente: isso não é feito automaticamente pelo tkinter, você tem que escrever uma função de callback que altera os atributos desejados,e  chama-la com o método `.after` da janela raiz da sua aplicação.